# POST google Places API - INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: google-places-api

```
{
  "location": {
    "lat": -33.8669710,
    "lng": 151.1958750
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Google Shoes!",
  "phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
  "address": "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Australia",
  "types": ["shoe_store"],
  "website": "http://www.google.com.au/",
  "language": "en-AU"
}
```

This one I tried and as well as other places without modifying the request structure with Indian places. I'm getting the following response:

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"results": [],
"status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

I'm not getting exactly what is the Issue, please revert back for the solution.

Comment: Please style your code!

Comment: It always helps to tell us what endpoint you are trying to use...luckily there aren't a whole lot of POST endpoints on the Places API :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify, I'm assuming that you are trying to use the add places endpoint on the Places API described [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) in the documentation.

The most likely problem is that you neglected to include your API key in the request URL, which should look like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Note that this endpoint is deprecated and that Google may remove it altogether at some point in the future.